# Как передать видео в post запросе?

Tags: java, android, spring, rest

Я сейчас пытаюсь сделать небольшое приложение по типу облака. По сути пользователь заходит в приложение, выбирает кнопку загрузить видео на облако, выбирает видео и нажимает кнопку отправить. Как в реализовать передачу файла типа mp4 на сервер, где он будет сохраняться, я не особо понимаю. Возможно это как-то делается с помощью InputStream, но решения на форумах я не нашел. Сервер и приложение пишу на Java, приложение само в android studio

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Отправка файла не зависит от его типа. Как именно отправлять данные на сервер зависит от используемых для этого библиотек и от того, в какой форме их ожидает сервер. Всё это следует описать в вопросе. Редактировать вопрос можно через кнопку [edit] под ним.